# If $f$ is bounded then convolution $f*g$ is continuous

Tags: lebesgue-integral, convolution

Define *convolution* $f$ of two functions $f_1, f_2: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$:
$$f(x) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_1(t) f_2(x-t)dt$$

Show that if $f_1$ is bounded, then $f$ is continuous.

I'm totally out of ideas to be honest. I only suppose that the previous problem in my assignment might have to do something with this (I'm allowed to link to this problem if needed):

> Let $f_1, f_2 \in L_1(\mathbb R)$. Show that $f_1(t)f_2(x-t)$ is measurable for all $t\in\mathbb R$ and $f(x) \in L_1(\mathbb R)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that for every $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$, if $f_t(x)=f(x-t)$ then
$$\tag{1}||f-f_t||_1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)-f(x-t)|dx\to 0$$
as $t\to 0$. (1) can be proved by using the fact that continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$. For these functions its easier to prove (1).

Now fix $\delta\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x$ and write
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(x-\delta)|=&\biggl|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_1(t)[f_2(x-t)-f_2(x-\delta-t)]dt\biggr|\\
&\leq M\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f_2(x-t)-f_2(x-\delta-t)|dt
\end{align}

where $M=\sup\{|f_1(t)|:t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Now use (1) and conclude that $f$ is indeed continuous.